# Creating graphical apps using C++

Tags: android, ios, qt, visual-c++, windows

I can say it's a long time I've been searching for the more correct way of using my *C++* skills for making real world apps. To me, most of the real world apps are graphical ones — those that have graphical environment and *GUI*s, like any ordinary app used on *MS Windows*. Of course there are many other (and probably vital) real world apps that are used for *embedded systems* that may don't have GUI.
Apart from *MS Windows*, there are quite a bit programs for other OSes like *Linux*.
On smartphones we also use *iOS* apps for devices made by *Apple* and *Android* ones as well.

My purpose is being able to create apps for the following platforms, in order of priority:
1- *MS Windows* platform
2- *iOS* and *Android* platform
3- Maybe in future, *Linux* platform or *embedded systems*
These are my *needs* generally.

Saying these matters, one idea comes into view: A good *IDE* that we can use our *C++* experience in it to make *cross-platform* apps that can also supports those 3 *needs* perfectly, yes, **Qt**.

But there seem to be some difficulties on using *Qt*. I read some of discussions said in the link below, but since I'm not familiar with it yet, I couldn't understand high-level subjects.
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/88685/why-arent-more-desktop-apps-written-with-qt

I know that each choice may have its own advantages and weaknesses. But finally I have to choose. 
My intention is to start learning *Qt* in near future and now to be sure that my chosen way for that near future (one or two months later) is not wrong!

Now I want you expert guys that please help this novice to make a correct decision.
My question on making the issue clear for me is that:
*Is Qt the best choice for my needs please? (Those three needs)*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Qt is not a good choice for point 2 ...and question is primarily opinion-based

Comment: But using Qt5 we will be able to create iOS and Android apps, not?

Comment: Qt sucks in many aspects, but the reality of the situation is that it is currently the best (or least bad) solution for C++ GUI application development. Is there a dilemma between Qt and something else here?

Comment: Yes, Qt 5 supports Android and iOS.

Comment: *the best (or least bad) solution for C++ GUI application development.* .... on desktop, because all "windows managers" on most desktop platforms have a lot of common ... but mobile devices ... not

Comment: @Selvin: Do you mean it's not best for servers?

Comment: *Qt is not a good choice for point 2* + *2- iOS and Android platform* ... did i meantion about servers? ... It is primarily opinion-based (my opinion): Qt is bad for creating mobile apps ...

Comment: No. But in your latter post you mentioned *on desktop* and I thought you meant desktop PCs.

Comment: @Selvin - I am using Qt for Android development and I have no problems with it. Maybe there are other factors attributing to your experience with it, if you have any, hopefully you are not talking without any.

Comment: Ops, looks like that's exactly what you do :)

Comment: Primarily opinion based question. Nevertheless I do use Qt in all of these environments. Qt is also nice for mobile development with the downside of the limitations of the framework (which can be extended by native JNI/Objective-C extensions). With Qt you can have a very quick start and have pretty good results, but it takes a long time to master. You can still use C++ for UI, but especially on mobile platforms QML (as for modern UI) is to be preferred.

Comment: The question you link to is ~5 years out of date. I like to point out one thing: if you think that adding an extra tool (like *moc*) to your build makes things more complex, you are dealing with a mostly trivial application anyway. As your application grows, you should be leveraging domain specific languages (DSLs) and adding your own tools into the build to make you more productive. Plus, as soon as you'll start depending on more libraries, your builds will be more complex anyway. I'd say that Qt is very economical in this area.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Qt Qml from Qt5

Qml allows to develop desktop and mobile applications. What you will need is to compile your application for new platform.

Qml is language for developing UI, but qml is javascript-based language and you can do logic in qml files. To provide your C++ classes you can just register they in C++ code.

P.S Qt for mobile platforms is good idea for fast-developed solutions for all mobile platform. If you want to get all available features and functionality from AndroidSDK, for example, you must use AndroidSDK or AndroidSDK wrappers.

P.S.S Qt is the best solution for crossplatform gui applications, and qt is easy to learn framework